# Define in PHP not accept space

Tags: php

I use `define()` function to make settings page for my site.
In my **settings.php**

```
define('DESCRIPTION', "Admin Dashboard Template");
define('TITLE', "Modern");
define('KEYWORDS', "admin,dashboard");
define('AUTHOR', "Minh Tan");
```

In my **index.php**

```
<?php include('config/settings.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <!-- Title -->
        <title><?php echo TITLE; ?> | Login - Sign in</title>

        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content=<?php echo DESCRIPTION; ?> />
        <meta name="keywords" content=<?php echo KEYWORDS; ?> />
        <meta name="author" content=<?php echo AUTHOR; ?> />
```

But when i run on my browser. It make this results:

[image: View on browser]

Help me! Thanks.

Comment: Seems wrong to me without double quotes `content=<?php echo DESCRIPTION; ?>` , it should be like `content="<?php echo DESCRIPTION; ?>"`

Comment: Just always use `key="value"` like you did with the `name` attribute. When you have a space in your value literal (without quotes) how should the client/browser "know" that the next word is still the value literal and not the name of the next attribute? It can't, therefore it parses it as the next attribute name as you can see in the browser source code view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your PHP statements in double quotes.. they go missing after your charset.

```
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo DESCRIPTION; ?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo KEYWORDS; ?>" />
    <meta name="author" content="<?php echo AUTHOR; ?>" />
```